# How do define Unomi segments based on events

Tags: apache-unomi

I want to define a Unomi segment that is based on page views, for example, "user has viewed a page with a category value of 'foo'" or 'user had viewed a page on the site with ID 'bar'".

I can't figure out how the Unomi data architecture connects profiles with events.

I've tried creating segments with an `eventPropertyCondition` and scorings with an `eventPropertyCondition`, and neither of them produce any results:

```
"type": "eventPropertyCondition",
"parameterValues": {
    "propertyName": "target.properties.pageInfo.categories",
    "comparisonOperator": "contains",
    "propertyValue": "cake"
}
```

What am I missing? It seems to me there's something fundamental about the Unomi data architecture that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

Define a segment with a `pastEventCondition`:

```
    "condition": {
        "type": "pastEventCondition",
        "parameterValues": {
            "operator": "eventsOccurred",
            "minimumEventCount": 1,
            "numberOfDays": 365,
            "eventCondition": {
                "type": "eventPropertyCondition",
                "parameterValues": {
                    "propertyName": "target.properties.pageInfo.categories",
                    "comparisonOperator": "contains",
                    "propertyValue": "cake"
                }
            }
        }
    },
```